# Inclusion between diagonalizable , unitary, normal and hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the inclusion between the following subsets of $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$: diagonalizable, unitary, normal and hermitian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will call the sets $\mathcal{D}$, $\mathcal{U}$, $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{H}$.

$\mathcal{H}\subset\mathcal{N}$ because $AA^*=A^2=A^*A$, remember that $A^*=A$.

$\mathcal{U}\subset\mathcal{N}$ because $AA^*=I=A^*A$, remember that $A^*=A^{-1}$.

$\mathcal{N}\subset\mathcal{D}$: It is a well-known theorem (for example you can find in Hoffman's book Linear Algebra) that every normal matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ is (unitarily) diagonalizable.

$\mathcal{D}$ is not contained in any of the other sets, because for example $\begin{pmatrix} 1&2\\0&2 \end{pmatrix}$ is diagonalizable (it has two distinct eigenvalues, namely 1 and 2) but it is not normal because $AA^T=\begin{pmatrix} 5&4\\4&4\end{pmatrix}$ and $A^T A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2\\2&8\end{pmatrix}$. This also implies that $\mathcal{D}\not\subset \mathcal{H}, \mathcal{U}$ either.

$\mathcal{H}\not\subset \mathcal{U}$ because any real diagonal matrix is Hermitian (as $A^*=A^T=A$)  but it does not necessarily have $|\det A|=1$. This also implies that $\mathcal{N}\not\subset \mathcal{U}$.

$\mathcal{U}\not\subset \mathcal{H}$ because for example $\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ is unitary ($AA^*=AA^T=I$) but is not Hermitian because $A^*=A^T\neq A$. This also implies that $\mathcal{N}\not\subset \mathcal{H}$.

Comment: Thank toy for the concise and clear answer!